# Converting raw pcm to speex?

Tags: actionscript, audio, encode, pcm, speex

For latency issues, I would like to send speex encoded audio frame data to a server instead of the raw PCM like I'm sending right now.

The problem is that I'm doing this in flash, and I want to use a socket connection to stream encoded spx frames of data.

I read the speex manual and it unfortunately does not go over the actual CELP algorithm used to convert pcm to spx data, it briefly introduces the use of excitation gains and how it grabs the filter coefficients.

It's libraries are in dlls- dead ends.

I really would like to create a conversion class in actionscript. Is this possible? Is there any documentation on this? I've been googling to no avail. You'd think there would be more documentation on speex out there...

And if I can't do this, what would be the most documente audio format to use?

thanks

Comment: I solved this by porting the speex library via alchemy :)

Comment: I'm glad that you can use Flash, but what if without flash? See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134936/how-to-call-speex-audio-decode-encode-in-html5-javascript-without-flash